# read pair of characters separated by \t c++

Tags: c++, getline

Friends,
I want to read a pair of characters separated by \t. I want to continue reading the input until user enters z for any of the characters.

Here are the options I thought:

```
while (cin>>ch1>>ch2)
{

// process ch1 & ch2

}

std::string str;

while (getline(cin, str) ){

//split string

}
```

Also, I want to validate the input to make sure that it is correct. Please suggest the best way. If this is a duplicate, please point me to the right one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite its name, you can use `std::getline()` to read other things than lines. It takes an optional third parameter denoting the delimiter. The default one is `'\n'`, but there's no reason you cannot use `'\t'` instead.

```
std::string line;
while( std::getline(is,line) ) { // read lines
  std::istringstream iss(line); 
  std::string field;
  while( std::getline(iss,field,'\t') { // read fields from line
    // process field
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that a waste to create 2 strings and an additional istringstream object to parse 3-char console input? :)

Comment: @Kotti: That might well be, but... For one, using `std::getline()` is definitely the easiest way to do this right. And then - why optimize a piece of code that waits for input from a user (or disk, which doesn't make all that much difference)? __If__ this code is ever found to be to slow (which I very much doubt), then it could always be replaced by optimized code later. Until then, readable and bug-free code rules.

Comment: I'm not sure what I should make of the fact that for two hours nobody noticed that my second call to `std::getline()` missed the `'\t'` parameter...

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach is good and very C++ish. The only problem is that it will read chars not only separated by `\t`, but also, for example, by plain space ();

The code would look the following way:

```
#include <iostream>

void main () {
   char c1, c2;
   while (std::cin >> c1 >> c2) {
      if (c1 == 'z' || c2 == 'z') break;
      // Otherwise do something useful
   }
}
```

Alternative approach is using `getche()` to take one symbol from input and show it on the screen. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

void main () {
   while (true) {
      char c1 = getche();
      char delimiter = getche();
      char c2 = getche();

      // Output end of line
      std::cout << std::endl;

      if (delimiter != '\t' || c1 == 'z' || c2 == 'z') break;
      // Otherwise do something useful
   }
}
```

Note that right now you don't have to press `enter` key after entering sequence. If you want to, you could add one more `getche()` call and check if the char equals 32 (enter code).

Comment: Generally speaking, your second approach is also fine, but requires additional body movements that parse string and, therefore, isn't recommended for such kinds of input sequences.

Comment: I don't think `<conio.h>` is a standard header.

Comment: I agree, but sometimes it's pretty useful (just to simplify writing of trivial console parsers)

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char c;
    int count = 0;
    string s; // s.reserve(LOTS);
    while(cin) while( cin.get(c) ) { // consume newlines as well
        if( c == '\t' ) continue;
        if( c == 'z' ) break;
        ++count;
        s += c;
    }
    cout << "got " << count << " tokens." << endl;
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```